# SPLIT_PART() entire column in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, split, amazon-redshift

How do I split_part an entire column(word-by-word)?
I am trying to split the column "answer" into each word.

eg **this is my dataset:**

| name | answer |
| --- | --- |
| Kate | i love cheese |
| Tom | i love bacon & eggs |

**this is what i want:**

| name | split_answer |
| --- | --- |
| Kate | i |
| Kate | love |
| Kate | cheese |
| Tom | i |
| Tom | love |
| Tom | bacon |
| Tom | & |
| Tom | eggs |

**this is my query:**

```
SELECT name, split_part(answer, ' ') AS split_asnwer FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

Split_part() can take 3 arguments - string, delimiter, and part number.

So you need to cross join with a numbers table that has all the integer values from 1 to the max number of parts in any string.  You can generate this numbers table with a recursive CTE or some like to just have a numbers table on hand.

The query will look something like (untested and off the cuff):

```
with recursive nums(n) as (
  select 1 as n
  union all
  select n + 1 
  from nums 
  where n < (select max(LEN(answer) - LEN(REPLACE(answer, ' ', '')) + 1) from table)
)
select name, split_part(answer, ' ', n) AS split_answer 
FROM table
cross join nums
where split_answer <> '';
```

Comment: I get this errorcode: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Comment: Ah yes, need the max() difference in length.  I'll update the answer but again still untested as I don't have a cluster up ATM